# Choose multi-section strings in PHP

Tags: php, string

How can I use PHP string functions like `strpos` or `preg_match` or any other functions to choose multi-section strings?
Imagine that I have several button classes names such as below in my site:
`Button-red`, `button_Blue`, `Button-green`, `Button-primary`,...

All of those button classes have three below properties:

- `Common section`, case-insensitive like: Button, button
- `Divider section`, one only like: - or _
- `Uncommon section`, case-insensitive like: red, blue, green, primary

I want to choose all of the **red-button** and **blue-button** buttons, regardless of lowercase or uppercase letter or divider between letters of theme?
My search result should match all of the: `button_Blue`, `Button-blue`, `button_Red`, `Button-red`.
 I don't want the search result to match the `blue` or `Red` alone.

Comment: you can use `stripos()` or the `i` modifier for `preg_match()` for insensitive case, if that's what the question is about.

Comment: Your question seems unclear / too broad.  Please improve your question so that we can understand what data you are dealing with and what you desire as output.

Comment: Matching a substring like `red` has a very high probability of over-matching.  Think about `buttered bread`  That will match using `stripos()` and a poorly constructed regex pattern.  Please provide a larger body of input data that you will be using as a haystack, then we can talk about needle-hunting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pattern:

```
/button[-_]red/i
```

[Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/moS8wO/1)

This will case-insensitively search for `button`, then a hyphen or underscore, then red.

---

This will match all of the red AND blue ones:

Pattern:  `/button[-_](red|blue)/i` or `/button[-_](?:red|blue)/i` (no capture on second pattern.)

[Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/moS8wO/2)

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani Are you saying you want to match all `button[-_]` substrings that are NOT followed by `red` or `blue`?  Like this: https://regex101.com/r/moS8wO/3 ?

Comment: My first pattern will match a single color at a time (red, in the example).  Is this what you mean?

Comment: My patterns do allow for case-insensitive matching and allow either `-` or `_` as the divider.  But now you are saying `red-button`, this is the opposite order of your question.  Did you visit my demo links?  They will show what my pattern does.

Comment: The second pattern of the two that match red and blue uses a non-capture group (see `?:`)  Here is that demo: https://regex101.com/r/moS8wO/4  If you want to match the entire line of code, then you can use something like this: https://regex101.com/r/moS8wO/5

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate you hearty and a lot ;-)